# Erro no firefox para focar input, após o blur do próprio elemento?

Tags: jquery

Preciso que o input fique em foco após ao `blur` caso não atenda ao solicitado.
Os dados desse `form` são dinamico são criados após uma consulta `ajax`, aqui no `snippet` o código funcionou, porém na minha aplicação após `blur` vai para o próximo input.

Exemplo do código:

```js
$('#txtPrazo').blur(function() {
  var days = parseInt($('#txtPrazo').val());
  if (days < 1 || days > 90) {
    $('#msg_days').html('* Insira um prazo entre 1 e 90 dias').css('color', 'red');
    $('#msg_data').html('');
    $('#txtPrazo').focus();
    console.log(days);
  } else {
    var hj = new Date();
    var prazo = new Date(hj.setDate(hj.getDate() + days));
    $('#msg_days').html('Previsão ').css('color', 'black');
    $('#msg_data').html(prazo.toLocaleDateString());
  }
});
```

```css
.input {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Prazo: 
<input class="input" type="number" min="1" max="90" id="txtPrazo" name="txtPrazo" value="45">
</label>
<span id="msg_days"></span><span id="msg_data"></span>
<br><br>
<label>Próximo: 
<input class="input" type="text" id="txtProx" name="txtProx">
</label>
```

Comment: No meu navegador funcionou. Mesmo copiando para fora do snippet. Qual o navegador está usando? E a versão?

Comment: @DiegoSantos estou testando em firefox e chrome em SO windows e ubuntu e acontece a mesma coisa, creio que deve ser pelo fato dessas funções js estarem em um arquivo separado, e este form ser criado dinamicamente. Mas teria que usar o js externo mesmo.

Comment: Hum, pode ser a ordem que o js seja importado. Faz assim, olha no chrome na tab network qual o ordem de importação. Pode ser isso...

Comment: está na seguinte ordem. `jquery.js` | `bootstrap.js` e `externo.js` mas o jquery quanto bootstrapa.js apraecem com status 200 e o externo como status 304 not Modified

Comment: Hummm, será cache? Acho que o snippet não guarda cache. Pra mim, é a primeira vez que executo. Pode ser que a versão nos seus navegadores estejam desatualizadas. Se não só debugando via navegador mesmo para saber.

Comment: Tenta limpar o cache e ver...

Comment: Limpando o cache funcionou no chrome e no IE, mas no firefox não, o que pode ser com o firefox?

Comment: Hum, bom menos mal né hahaha. Podemos fazer o mesmo teste? No mozzila também tem a aba network. Dá uma olhada na ordem de importação. Veja no console se aparecem erros. Se nada disso der certo, tente debugar. Por exemplo, ao invés de chamar num evento, o blur, chame como uma função e veja passo a passo. se for o caso, ponha *debug;* na função para ver rodando passo a passo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma

> troquei

```
$("#txtPrazo").focus();
```

> Por

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#txtPrazo").focus();
}, 0);
```

```js
$('#txtPrazo').blur(function() {
  var days = parseInt($('#txtPrazo').val());
  if (days < 1 || days > 90) {
    $('#msg_days').html('* Insira um prazo entre 1 e 90 dias').css('color', 'red');
    $('#msg_data').html('');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#txtPrazo").focus();
    }, 0);
    console.log(days);
  } else {
    var hj = new Date();
    var prazo = new Date(hj.setDate(hj.getDate() + days));
    $('#msg_days').html('Previsão ').css('color', 'black');
    $('#msg_data').html(prazo.toLocaleDateString());
  }
});
```

```css
.input {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Prazo: 
<input class="input" type="number" min="1" max="90" id="txtPrazo" name="txtPrazo" value="45">
</label>
<span id="msg_days"></span><span id="msg_data"></span>
<br><br>
<label>Próximo: 
<input class="input" type="text" id="txtProx" name="txtProx">
</label>
```